# openssl using -dateopt causes "Invalid date format: iso_8601" error

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, command-line-interface, iso8601

How to set the option `-dateopt` for the `openssl` properly?

An example of a self signed certificate generation:

```
openssl req \
-x509 \
-days 10 \
-nodes \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-keyout "$PWD/self.key" \
-out "$PWD/self.crt" \
-subj "/C=US/ST=STATE/L=CITY/O=ORG_NAME/OU=OU_NAME/CN=CN_OR_FQDN_OR_SERVER_NAME"
```

gives me two files in the current directory:

```
self.key
self.crt
```

To check the end date of the `self.crt` i run:

```
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in "$PWD/self.crt"
```

that returns the proper result:

> notAfter=Oct  4 16:05:59 2022 GMT

but if I use the `-dateopt` switch [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-x509.html):

> ***-dateopt***. Specify the date output format. Values are: rfc_822 and ***iso_8601***. Defaults to rfc_822.

this way:

```
openssl x509 -enddate -dateopt iso_8601 -noout -in "$PWD/self.crt"
```

I get the error (ec=1):

> Invalid date format: iso_8601

Perhaps the reason is somewhere around these lines  [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/1bf649b5998ac98511203f54ce954eccfaf75467/apps/x509.c#L347):

```
case OPT_DATEOPT:
   if (!set_dateopt(&dateopt, opt_arg())) {
       BIO_printf(bio_err,
       "Invalid date format: %s\n", opt_arg());

       goto err;
   }
   break;
```

or [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/openssl-3.0.2/apps/lib/apps.c#L1183):

```
int set_dateopt(unsigned long *dateopt, const char *arg)
{
    if (strcasecmp(arg, "rfc_822") == 0)
        *dateopt = ASN1_DTFLGS_RFC822;
    else if (strcasecmp(arg, "iso_8601") == 0)
        *dateopt = ASN1_DTFLGS_ISO8601;
    return 0;
}
```

or maybe it is related to the issue:
[-dateopt option only affects x509 -dates option output](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18557)

I would like to ask how to set the `-dateopt` properly in order to get the `-enddate` in the `ISO 8601` date format?

I tried: `iso_8601`, `ISO_8601`, `"iso 8601"`, `ISO 8601`, `iso8601`, `ISO8601`, `iso8601` but none of them worked.

My:

```
openssl version
```

is: [OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/openssl-3.0.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

The relevant function was broken in openssl 3.0.3 and lower since the function set_dateopt (which you quote) always returned 0:

```
int set_dateopt(unsigned long *dateopt, const char *arg)
{
    if (OPENSSL_strcasecmp(arg, "rfc_822") == 0)
        *dateopt = ASN1_DTFLGS_RFC822;
    else if (OPENSSL_strcasecmp(arg, "iso_8601") == 0)
        *dateopt = ASN1_DTFLGS_ISO8601;
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to be fixed in openssl 3.0.4. See [issue #18553](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18553) for bug report and [issue #18554](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/18554) for fix.

Comment: I got that feeling but could not believe that a CLI option was not a subject for the tests and got fixated on my way of passing that argument. I see that now tests for the `-dateopt` are added to [test/recipes/25-test_x509.t](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/67e1b558e67a3bee1f20f8a9e067211b440404f8#diff-fa4dafbb45e7875b73dfaeeded7a1bbd484b230c9aee31cc48ae86a86a8fcf11). Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Unlucky for the `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` users the update is not available yet (Sept 24 2022). [Package openssl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/openssl) version is `3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6`